# The use of [...] operator in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was going through a **typescript code (with Angular 2)** on website and I found following :

```
let episodesCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.episodes))

this.episodes=[...episodesCopy,this.otherEpisodes.pop()];
```

I want to understand whether operator `...` in `...episodesCopy` is a typescript operator or a javascript operator? and what exactly it does?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: I was not aware of [...] operator is of Javascript. Even in my question I specifically mentioned about Typescript. What is the reason behind downvoting?

Answer (score 2):

That is the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator or spread syntax.  It is essentially taking an expression (usually an array) and converting it into multiple statements.